# Need help integrating plugin into theme

Tags: plugins, php

I'm setting up a new site running the paid MH Newsdesk theme and I'm having trouble integrating the Co-Authors Plus (https://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/) plugin. I know my way around CSS but am having trouble integrating the template tags from the plugin into the appropriate place within my theme pages. I think the MH Newsdesk theme in particular heavily modifies how authors are integrated into posts.

Details on Co-Authors integration here: https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/incorporate-co-authors-plus-template-tags-into-your-theme/

The theme has a separate "authorbox" template that is called upon from various other template pages. I would imagine if I can correctly modify this "authorbox" template it would integrate elsewhere (unless that's part of the problem?). Here's the authorbox code:

```
<?php /* Template for displaying the author box on posts */
$author_ID = get_the_author_meta('ID');
if (!is_attachment() && get_the_author_meta('description', $author_ID)) { ?>
    <h4 class="widget-title"><span><?php _e('About the Author', 'mh-newsdesk'); ?></span></h4>
    <section class="author-box clearfix">
        <div class="author-box-avatar"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_author_posts_url($author_ID)); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar

($author_ID, 100); ?></a></div>
        <h5 class="author-box-name"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_author_posts_url($author_ID)); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr

(get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_ID)); ?></a></h5>
        <div class="author-box-desc"><?php echo get_the_author_meta('description', $author_ID); ?></div>
    </section><?php
} ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried and where is the issue? Do you have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and is it showing errors?

Comment: The issue is that once you install the plugin you still need to go in and edit templates to use the plugin. You're replacing the_author() tags with customized code. The whole point of the plugin is to show two authors for a single post, both in the byline (simple links to their author pages) and two bio boxes at the bottom.